# How to hold multi request if it comes at a same time in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, singleton

I'm using Spring Boot, my app is working based on **Date and Time**. The problem is, if one request comes from the jsp page, I have to loop the json object which comes from jsp page and save those value in db. For one request, there will be *6 insertion in table*. So if n request comes, then **n*6** insertion.

But if all request comes at a same time (***even milliseconds are same for a particular time***), what I need is, there should be **time labs** between requests (at least in milliseconds). Now it doesn't show any time gap if multi requests come at a same time. Spring Boot uses threads. I tried to use "singleton". But it doesn't work. I'm not good in Singleton design, but I referred few tutorials. I use a Recursive function to create new time for each request.

> - singleton: only one instance is created (default scope)
> - prototype: new instance is created everytime prototype bean is referenced.
> - request: one instance for a single HTTP request.
> - session: one instance for an HTTP Session

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveCategory(@ModelAttribute("gaugeForm") Gauge gauge, @RequestParam(value = "values") String json)
{
    //makeing json to List using ObjectMapper

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String nowDateTime =checkDateTime(now.toString()); // checking and getting if the date and time already exists in db using recursive function.

    //A simple example what I do.   
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        gauge.setName(i);
        gauge.setDatetime(nowDateTime ) // now dateTime
        gaugeService.saveOrUpdate(gauge);
    }
}
```

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gauge")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Scope(value = "singleton") // try to create an instance at a time
public class Gauge {
    private String name;
    private String datetime;

    //constructors, gettters and setters
}
```

**Recursive function**

```
public String checkDateTime(String dateTime) {
    if (gaugeService.isDateTimeInDB(dateTime)) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        return checkDateTime(now.toString());
    } else {
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

**The following image shows how exactly I need**. First 6 insertions (1st request) are same in time and next 6 insertions (2nd request) are same in time  but different from first.

[image: This is an example what I need]

Summary: hold all request until one request saves in database.

If my approach is wrong, please let me know any other approaches.

Comment: Why do you need that? The threadpool used to handle request already throttle incoming requests. Unless you want to process your requests in incoming order

Comment: @varman Why don't you handle this on the DB side use transaction with isolation and propagation. Lock on the table or a row then process a new transaction for next request.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I need it to process sql commands like distinct

Comment: @mallikarjun I just read few tutorials, might `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) ` help me?

Comment: @varman google for it and [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/transactional-annotation.html) simple one to start.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an unique uuid on the client side and pass it inside these 6 requests, on the server side you can put them into a map by the uuid key and save once all 6 requests will be received.

Comment: This might be a good idea. There is a huge process within the controllers, I just covered a bit. But if a lot of request comes, the speed of processing will be down. IS there any smarter idea?

Comment: its a platform app. So I can't say how many RPS will be. And another problem is, if few guys working with their own pc, can we hold the request?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use transactions to serialize your requests into the database and use an incrementing field as a pseudo-timestamp or relax the criteria of 1 millisecond?

By using a transaction you can guarantee requests will be stored serially and don't have to worry about that logic in your controller.

The database will in all likelihood be writing to a page held in memory (and to the write-ahead log) so I don't think there is any guaranteed way to ensure a time-lapse between records of at least 1 millisecond.

The best you can do is to suffix the actual time with an additional "timestamp" (some auto-incrementing field managed by the database) or use "ticks" (rather than milliseconds) along with database time (i.e. the database TIME function), rather than client time.